# Php upload image to directory not working

Tags: php

I know there's questions on this issue but I'm trying to get images uploaded to a directory using move_uploaded_file. I'm using the example from the php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php but I'm getting an Undefined index: file. File is the name of my file input type so I'm not sure why it's undefined.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="MoveImages.php" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add Images" value="Add Photo"/>
</form>
```

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/Users/Jane/Desktop/NE';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");

?>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.
That attribute is required when you are uploading file.